# How to backup a Caffe (DL framework) project? The Caffe folder (downloaded from GitHub) can't be copied or compressed

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am using Ubuntu18.04 and Caffe deep learning framework to do my project. However, when I tried to backup my project, I found that the Caffe folder (downloaded from GitHub) can't be copied or compressed.

Here is what I did:

1. Download Caffe from GitHub, and install it.
2. Do some modification to the source code for my project.
3. Backup the whole Caffe folder.
   However, if I copy the folder to a USB flash drive, I will have a
   folder that misses files (I compared the size and number of files of two folders). If I compress the folder then copy it to the USB flash drive, then I get error says I can't open the compressed file.

I wonder if I did anything wrong, what is the correct way of backup Caffe project?

Thanks.

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if your USB drive is corrupted or too full for the size of the directory. Try copying/compressing somewhere else and see if it works. It probably has nothing to do with Caffee itself.

Comment: @Erwan Thanks for your feedback. I did the same, I copy it from `Ubuntu Home` folder to the `Ubuntu Desktop`. The original folder has `111,0444 items, totalling 271.3GB`, the copied one has only `386 items, totalling 39.6GB`.

Comment: ok that's weird... use diff -r between the source directory and the copy to compare the directories, see what's missing, then check the permissions for the missing files.

Comment: @Erwan I use the command `diff -r ./caffe/ caffe/`, but it returns nothing. I think I just did something wrong here.

Comment: ./caffe and caffe/ are the same directory. for example if you copied caffe in the Desktop dir you should do diff -r caffee Desktop/caffee

Comment: Btw are you sure you have enough space on your partition? 271GB is a very big directory. To give you an idea, the full Ubuntu system requires around 20GB.

Comment: @Erwan Thanks. I checked the space, and I have enough on my partition. In the end, It's the problem with file permissions. Would you like to give an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem is due to wrong file permissions for certain files. Assigning read permissions to the full directory should solve it:

```
chmod -R u+r <caffe directory>
```